# How do I restore visual mode selection highlighting?

Tags: syntax-highlighting, visual-mode, colorscheme, highlight

Somehow, over the last few days, the visual mode in Vim no longer flips the background highlight, as it used to.  Now, if the file is recognized by something it can syntax highlight, it seems to unbold and darken colored text.  But, for non-syntax highlighted text, or files it doesn't know the syntax of, there is no highlighting at all.  Visual mode still selects normally for selections, but there's not visual difference over a selected area for non-syntax highlighted text.

How can I clear/correct/reset the visual mode selection highlighting?

Clarifying Details:

- Vim 7.4
- Vundle for plugins

  - I've tried removing and disabling any new plugins, no effect
- `vim -u NONE` seems to restore it to what I would expect
- Turning on `set :hlsearch` properly enables search highlighting as usual

Comment: If `vim -u NONE` fixes it, then you're after this: http://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/2003/how-do-i-debug-my-vimrc-file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Debugging my `.vimrc` file led me to discover that my `colorscheme` seemed to be the cause.  Changing it to something else fixed the problem.

Answer (score 13):

I had this issue as well because I had switched to the "evening" color scheme in my ~/.vimrc file so that my comments were easier to read on a dark background:

```
:colorscheme evening
```

To restore visual mode highlighting I had to also add this:

```
:highlight Visual cterm=reverse ctermbg=NONE
```

Comment: I have same issue as you. I usually `set background=dark` which is similar with `colorscheme evening`, and in tmux, the visual mode will lose its highlight. Now I get it back. Thank you for your answer.